# M-Audio Delta 1010LT on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

I have 12.04 64bit installed, my soundcard is a Delta 1010LT, it seems to be partially detected, I've been following steps here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting/

`lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` shows this:

```
04:07.0 Multimedia audio controller: VIA Technologies Inc. ICE1712 [Envy24] PCI Multi-Channel I/O Controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: VIA Technologies Inc. M-Audio Delta 1010LT
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 22
I/O ports at ec00 [size=32]
I/O ports at e880 [size=16]
I/O ports at e800 [size=16]
I/O ports at e480 [size=64]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_ice1712
```

`aplay` shows this:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: M1010LT [M Audio Delta 1010LT], device 0: ICE1712 multi [ICE1712 multi]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In the sound settings on the desktop all I see is the ICE1712 S/PDIF, which I don't use, I want to use the individual outputs on the card, I'm not so bothered about inputs, I just want the playback for now.

If I open alsamixer in the console, I see all of the output and input channels, i've raised the volume on them but I don't get anything in the sound settings on the desktop and when I play any sound, I hear nothing.

Can someone help?

Comment: While in `alsamixer` interface can you select your card with F6 key? any improvements then?

Comment: Yes, I the card is in there, along with the nvidia hdmi thing which I don't want to use, the 1010LT is selected by default.  I see a lot of channels on there and I've put the volume up on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use pulseaudio? If so, I believe this card works best with alsa+jack. Try disabling pulseaudio, and using a jack application.